# Read console output while program is running c#

Tags: c#, networking

I have a C# program that I want to have run an external program and while the program is running, it needs to read the console output and send it in JSON format to a server. This is what I was thinking. Will it work?

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process app = Process.Start(psi);

while (true)// what do I loop on?
{
    string line = "{ \"message\": \"" + app.StandardOutput.ReadLine() + "\" }";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "/results/:" + runId + "/logs");
    request.ContentType = "text/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question. Did you try it? "Will it work" is kind of a vague question - we'll probably need more specifics about what happens when you try it, and what you expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event of `Process` class, to not block execution of the program, and do not run the code inside `while(true)` loop !.

If main program just has to stand and wait for this process exit, can do

```
Process app = Process.Start(psi);
//  read code, subscription to event described above, 
// and processing it inside event handler

app.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process app = Process.Start(psi);

StreamReader reader = app.StandardOutput;

do
{
   string line = "{ \"message\": \"" + reader.ReadLine() + "\" }";

   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "/results/:" + runId + "/logs");
   request.ContentType = "text/json";
   request.Method = "POST";
   using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
   {
       tw.WriteLine(line);
   }

}while(!reader.EndOfStream);

app.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead think about changing the redirection of the output window to something like an event log or even a text file.  Then, have your web application periodically check the event log or text file, while keeping track of where it left off, to then only send the new results.

Comment: I would say the opposite.  reading from direct access to standard output is much better than trying to synchronize access to a text file between the two processes.